# What is the sqlite default column type?

Tags: sqlite

In one of our company's scripts I found a sqlite create table script that for one of the columns the data type definition is missing. What is the default value of a column type at the time of table creation?

```
create table x(
y, 
z int
);
```

In the above simplified example y column is under question.

When I try to check the column with

```
pragma table_info(x)
```

the information for y column is missing.

Comment: The type stays empty - see below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity

3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.

So we can assume that default type is a BLOB.

Answer (score 2):

There are no types of a column only a type affinity. In the case it's omitted, the type affinity is `NUMERIC`. You can read up on it here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: No, it is NUMERIC

Comment: @pexea12 No, for sqlite3 the affinity rules as already pointed out in #3 of section 3.1 of the linked page... the affinity is BLOB if **"no type is specified"**.  It only defaults to NUMERIC if all other conditions fail, like if you declare it as, for example, MyFoobarType.  If you are certain that the documentation is incorrect, then add more useful info not just a "no its not" comment.

Comment: Actually if no type is specified during the create statement no type is returned see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

#### Type metadata stays empty

In the current version of the page [sqlite datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) this is written:

> **3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity**
>
> The affinity of a column is determined by the declared type of the column, according to the
> following rules in the order shown:
>
> 1. If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned
>    INTEGER affinity.
> 2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR",
>    "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the
>    type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT
>    affinity.
> 3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no
>    type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
> 4. If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL",
>    "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
> 5. Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.
>
> Note that the order of the rules for determining column affinity is important. ....

So the answer for the default type depends.

#### Test for type

1. Create an empty table   `CREATE TABLE TestDefaultColum(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, NameLast, NameFirst);`
2. Get the table metadata  `PRAGMA table_info(TestDefaultColum);`

This returns no type information for the columns

[image: SQLite metadata for for columns without a type]

Adding a record into the empty table

```
INSERT INTO TestDefaultColum (NameLast) Values ('Dilbert');
```

To query the type this can be done:

```
PRAGMA table_info(TestDefaultColum); 
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('TestDefaultColum');
```

**The type metadata stays empty even after a value is inserted.**

See

[image: SQLite type of columns]